# Retrieving FTP file over max transfer size

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I had a coworker upload an 8GB file to our FTP server.  When I try to download it, I'm given '553 Cannot send file larger than 4 gigabytes.' message. Are there any hacks to get around this transfer limit? By the way, the coworker left the company and I need this file.

I've tried searching for some kind of tool that would work directly on the server and split up the file into manageable chunks (like 7zip on a remote location), however there aren't any tools as far as I know.

I don't know all the specs on the server, but it's running Windows.

Comment: Can you get in contact with the person responsible for administering the server? They should be able to retrieve the file for you. I'm not sure you're going to be able to find a solution otherwise.

Comment: First you need to specify your FTP-client and Windows-server version (of ftp-server version). For example: FileZilla FTP client include support for large (> 4 GB) files. But your FTP-server also needs to support it. According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185093) the FTP-server from Microsoft did not support it in the past (but got fixed with an SP) Of course this also depends on if the server allows bigger transfers.

Comment: @JoshR I know the server admin, but that would be my last hope.  I'd really like to see if there's any possible way to do it on my own.